# Marie assembly Code from average to subtraction

Tags: assembly, marie

Could someone can solve this question, i can't change it to subtraction. Could someone help even though i change the code.

```
LOOP, LOAD X
    SUBT TEN
    SKIPCOND 000   /if X = 10
    JUMP LOOP2     /take average after X = 10;

    CLEAR           /BEGIN INPUTING NUMBERS FOR AVERAGE
    INPUT
    STORE TEMP
    CLEAR

IF, LOAD X
    SUBT 1
    SKIPCOND 800
    JUMP STOREFIRST

    CLEAR
    LOAD TEMP
    SUBT MIN
    SKIPCOND 000
    JUMP FINDMAX

ELSE, SKIPCOND 800
    JUMP FINDMIN

CONTINUE, CLEAR
    LOAD TEMP
    ADD Y           /add Y to the input
    STORE Y         /save new value
    CLEAR
    LOAD X         /INCREMENT COUNTER
    ADD ONE
    STORE X
    CLEAR
    JUMP LOOP       /RESTART LOOP

FINDMAX, CLEAR
    LOAD TEMP
    STORE MAX
    JUMP CONTINUE

FINDMIN, CLEAR
    LOAD TEMP
    STORE MIN
    JUMP CONTINUE

STOREFIRST, LOAD TEMP
    STORE MIN
    STORE MAX
    JUMP CONTINUE

LOOP2, LOAD Y    /LOAD ALL THE ADDED NUMBERS
    SKIPCOND 800     /WHEN Y = 0
    JUMP PRINT       /GO TO OUTPUT

    SUBT TEN         /SUBTRACT 10 UNTIL REACH 0
    STORE Y          /STORE NEW NUMBER
    CLEAR
    LOAD DIFF     /EACH LOOP ADD 1 TO Difference
    ADD ONE
    STORE DIFF
    CLEAR
    JUMP LOOP2

PRINT, LOAD DIFF
    Output
    CLEAR
    LOAD MIN
    Output
    CLEAR
    LOAD MAX
    OUTPUT
    CLEAR

    HALT

TEN, DEC 10
ONE, DEC 1
X, DEC 0          /USE TO INPUT 10 NUMBERS, COUNTER
Y, DEC 0          /ALL NUMBERS INPUT ADDED 
MIN, DEC 0     
MAX, DEC 0
TEMP, DEC 0
DIFF, DEC 0    /Difference OF Y minus BY X
```

Could someone can solve this question, i can't change it to subtraction. Could someone help even though i change the code.

Comment: Do you know what this code does and how it works? Generally speaking, it is better to start with an algorithm that does exactly what you want rather than some assembly that doesn't. That algorithm can be pseudo code or better yet C code (or Java or other high level language code) that you can test and show that it works. Easier to translate a working algorithm in C or Java into assembly than modify assembly written for a different purpose, especially if you don't have a working algorithm for what you need it to do.